# Can players buy other players properties by proxy?

Tags: monopoly

In the game monopoly, can two players create an agreement to proxy buy properties on a players behalf.

For example: player one gives player two $100, in exchange if player two lands on boardwalk, player one will give player two the $400 dollars, player two purchases boardwalk, and gives it to player one. Effectively allowing player one to purchase boardwalk by having player two land on it for a fee.

While this doesn't break any of the wrote rules in the game as far as I know, is this prohibited in any way?

Comment: I can't see a rule against it but why would you want to play this way?  it doesn't sound like a good deal for player 2.

Comment: If you don't buy a property, it is put up for auction. So this way circumvents the auction and probably pisses of other players.

Answer (score 7):

Three related posts that all have decent notations of official rules:

- [Regarding when trading and such can occur](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/in-monopoly-is-it-ok-for-a-third-party-to-make-a-trade-with-a-player-who-is-abo)
- [Regarding the order of actions in a turn](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6563/what-are-the-order-of-actions-in-monopoly)
- [Regarding the giving or loaning of money to another player](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/in-the-official-rules-of-monopoly-can-you-offer-immunity-to-other-players-in-de)

I focused on the following sections from each post.

*From Link 1*

> Selling Property: This may only be done at any time **other than** after a player rolls the dice, but before they have paid ([Rent [and/or] Tax]) to ([another player [and/or] the Bank.])

*From Link 2*

> The only action which is doable outside one's turn (according to the instructions I've got off-line, in my deluxe box) are buying auctioned properties, buying or trading properties with other players, and using cards that say "use at any time."

*From Link 3*

> Another way to give money to another player is to sell them an unimproved property for $0, then buy it back for the amount you wish to give them.

See the links for more complete details, but the three posts combine give me the understanding that **yes** you can. You would complete the steps as follows.

Player 1 give Player 2 a gift of $100
Player 2 rolls
Player 2 lands on Boardwalk
Player 1 gives Player 2 a gift of $400
Player 2 buys Boardwalk
Player 2 sells Boardwalk to Player 1 for $0

However, there is nothing to force them to finish the transactions. Player 1 may give Player 2 $500 and Player 2 may decide to just keep it and never trade it back. It would be a tactical move that destroyed the possibility of an alliance, but it's within the rules since the money was a "gift."

Best of luck and may your friendships outlast the board.

Answer (score 1):

If player two lands on Boardwalk (which is currently) occupied, he has two choices:

1. Buy the property. He needs to have money to buy it.
2. Decline. The property is put up for auction. All players can bid and the property is sold to the highest bidder.

In your option, player one pays player two before player two purchases Boardwalk and gives it to player one. The order of events is flawed. If player two has enough money, he could buy the property and sell it to player one. 
But if player two hasn't enough money, he can't buy it, so there will be an auction.

Doing it your way pisses off other players. And the main goal in playing a game is to have fun. It is perfectly acceptable to outsmart another player if you act within the rules. But if you enter a gray area, people get frustrated.

Comment: A good answer to this question needs to _directly_ address the sub-question "When precisely are players allowed to make trades?". If players are allowed to trade/gift in between the time a player lands on a space and the time the player chooses to purchase or not, then OP's sequence is legal.

Comment: And re "Doing it your way pisses off other players": I don't think it makes sense to present such an opinion as fact. Among my acquaintances, this strategy would be completely socially acceptable - in fact it's quite tame compared to some of the contracts they've drawn up during the game.

Comment: To address @BenjaminCosman's concern, there doesn't appear to be any rules against the timing of "gifting" money, so it seems to be legal. Additionally, my group would likewise see this as a strategic investment and would probably accept this kind of move. They would also probably betray each other the way I have outlined in my own answer. It seems legal, and the results may be very interesting.

Comment: players could transfer the money back and forth before any potential landing on boardwalk...